# C++ CLR String Globally Without Ref Class

Tags: string, c++-cli, clr

I am trying to use a CLR string globally without a ref class but when i try and display the string i get " True " in the console however when i display it in a message box i get what i want it to say. Any ideas? Code :

```
#include <Windows.h>
#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;

static String^* str;

int main()
{
    str = (String^*)"Hellooo";
    Console::WriteLine(str);
    Console::ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: where's the code you use for the message box?

Comment: MessageBox(0, (LPCTSTR)str, "HERE", MB_OK);

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function to convert `std::string` to `String^` then print it on console:

```
    String^ CppStringToSysString(const std::string& s)
    {
      return Marshal::PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)(char*)s.c_str());
    }
```